# Camera shakes like heat shimmer or mirage

Tags: animation, camera

Suddenly my camera has started to warble or shake when I play my animation (looks like heat waves/shimmer...).  There are no modifiers on the camera. It isn't noticeable in wireframe or solid viewport shading, but is very noticeable in look dev and rendered.  I'm using eevee, Blender 2.8.  Please help.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe the rendering a frame takes longer than it the time a frame is displayed. Try properly rendering your animation.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, the camera's clip start was too small (0.001), which was fine for an interior shot, but as soon as the camera went outside it had to be set higher (0.100).
Cheers